# Android Emulator Does Appear, but it only shows a black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

So when I launched the android device, it does appear the device, but the screen is black, nothing change
I have tried to press the turn on the button and still doesn't work.

I have tried to reinstall the android studio, wipe data on the emulator, and a cold boot, but it doesn't work at all.

I'm installing my android studio in local disk D instead of  C, so all of the Android SDK tools and avd are in the local disk D. I have change all the environment variables

Is this the problem? or there is something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling Riot Vanguard fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Genymotion`. Here is the download link from the official website [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/download/). To use this, simply go to your project and start the genymotion application. After the application started, choose genymotion as your  `AVD` in your android studio.